# Firebase realtime database permission denied even with the simpliest rules for authenticated users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

First of all, I beg your pardon because I'm not a developer and for sure I'll make mistakes triying to explain my problem.

I have an app made with Kodular that works with Firebase authentication and Realtime Database. It works perfect when the rules are these:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read" : "auth != true",
    ".write" : "auth != true"
  }
}
```

Or these:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

But if I try to change them to allow only authenticated users, even the most simple way, it results in permission denied message.

```
    {
      "rules": { 
          "$userUID": {
              ".read": "auth.uid != null && auth.uid == $userUID",
              ".write": "auth.uid != null && auth.uid == $userUID"           
    }
}
```

I've asked in the kodular community but nobody have an answer to this problem.
I think is not a sintax problem, because I have copy-pasted rules from several helping forums and the Firebase documentation and it never worked, always the same problem.

Any clue to solve the problem will be apreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a typo that you're missing a closing bracket after the `".write"` block?

Comment: Yes, was a typo, sorry, I edit it. Without the bracket the rules can't be published as you sure know. And I always test the rules in the "rules test zone" to be sure they are right, but even with the test passed, the permission is denied. Thanks for your help.